# iOS - Shared View in different View Controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I need to add shared view (analogue of TabBar, custom menu) to few ViewControllers. I'm going to use Singletone:

```
static BottomBarMenu *sharedBottomBarMenu = nil;

+ (BottomBarMenu *)sharedBottomBarMenu
{
static dispatch_once_t once_token = 0;
dispatch_once(&once_token, ^{
    sharedBottomBarMenu =  [[BottomBarMenu  alloc] init];
    [self setupMenu];
});

return sharedBottomBarMenu;
}
```

, where `setupMenu` is customization method (background, button images, etc.)

How should I connect my UIView class to different View Controllers? I've realized interface on Storyboard.

Comment: This is an incredibly bad idea...

Answer (score 0):

You can't share a single view between view controllers. A view can only be a subview of a single view.

Comment: I'm going  to realize menu like TabBar - custom menu with few buttons, which allows to navigate between viewcontrollers. I cannot subclass TabBar, because I dont need to have icons of all views (but I need to add this "tabbar" to all views).